# Android JNI JavascriptCore JSEvaluateScript, JSObjectMakeFunction, JSObjectCallAsFunction give Parse or Range Error

Tags: javascript, android, c++, java-native-interface, javascriptcore

I'm using JavaScriptCore and JNI and i'm trying to use some JS code in my Open GL ES android application.

If i call `JSEvaluateScript, JSObjectMakeFunction, JSObjectCallAsFunction` in the main loop, without using a timer (so before the first call to `on_draw_frame`), all is ok.

But if i try `JSEvaluateScript, JSObjectMakeFunction, JSObjectCallAsFunction` in `drawInRest`, or/and using an implementation of setTimeout like

```
setTimeout ( function () {
    console.log("i'm in the callback");
}, 1000 );
```

I'm getting a Parse Error (but the syntax is correct) or a Range Error : max call stack exceeded (i'm 100% sure that there is no recursive call here).

More info : 
i get this between the call of a `JSEvaluateScript` (outside the `on_draw_frame`, main loop) and the second one (calling from `on_draw_frame`, when the trigger the setTimeout callback)

```
11-08 15:52:03.905: D/libEGL(2916): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
11-08 15:52:03.915: D/(2916): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a1d68d8, tid 2916
11-08 15:52:03.925: D/libEGL(2916): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
11-08 15:52:03.935: D/libEGL(2916): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
11-08 15:52:03.976: W/EGL_emulation(2916): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-08 15:52:03.985: D/OpenGLRenderer(2916): Enabling debug mode 0
11-08 15:52:04.026: D/(2916): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a1e5ae0, tid 2929
```

EDIT :
I find where the errors happens : after the first JNI Call.

I explain :

In the first JNI Call, i create my javaScriptView, which contains a static ref to my `JSGlobalContext`. Then i call `JSEvaluateScript` to evaluate my script, which do a setTimeout.

I configure OpenGL ES to, at each `on_draw_frame`, it call a JNI method to do the `on_draw_frame` in c++. So after some JNI Call (depends of the timer of the setTimeout), the callback of the setTimeout is call and crash.

Any ideas to how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try run `JSEvaluateScript`, `JSObjectMakeFunction` and `JSObjectCallAsFunction` in one thread.
If you call on_draw_frame from `onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)`, this is called from another thread than `onCreate()` in MainActivity (in which you init js), so it can be cause of your problem.
Try init js once in onDrawFrame(GL10 gl).